# Plotting a random function f(x) and f(x)+sin(x) with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm plotting a function f(x) with random values as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=blue, samples=150]  plot[domain=0:10] (\x,rand) node[below] {$f(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to plot a new Function g(x) which is defined as g(x)=f(x)+sin(x). Is there a way to do that?

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: DO you mean using the same random points for both?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) And thank you for providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is easily possible if you set the seed directly before the plot and use the same `samples` and `domain` settings.

If you don’t want to set the seed manually, you can store it before the first plot and re-set it afterwards.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfmathstoreseed#1{\let#1\pgfmath@rnd@z}
\let\pgfmathrestoreseed\pgfmathsetseed
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathstoreseed\mySeed
  \draw[color=blue, samples=250] plot[domain=0:10] (\x,rand/10) node[right] {$f(x)$};
  \pgfmathrestoreseed\mySeed
  \draw[color=red,  samples=250] plot[domain=0:10] ({\x,rand/10 + sin (\x r)})
                                                       node[below] {$f(x) + \sin x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetseed{126838}
  \draw[color=blue, samples=250] plot[domain=0:10] (\x,rand/10) node[right] {$f(x)$};
  \pgfmathsetseed{126838}
  \draw[color=red,  samples=250] plot[domain=0:10] ({\x,rand/10 + sin (\x r)})
                                                       node[below] {$f(x) + \sin x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.