# Coloring a region bounded by curves

Tags: tikz-pgf

I got a problem when I want to color the region bounded by curves `\sigma^{(0)}, \sigma^{(1)}, \sigma^{(0)}`. I use the command  `\draw[fill=red!30, opacity=.5] (h2)--(h3)--(h4)--cycle;`   but it is colored only the triangle formed by 3 vertices `v_0`, `v_1`, `v_2`. Like in the image below:

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{epsfig,psfrag}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym,amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.2in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.3in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.7in}
\setlength{\voffset}{-.7in}
\setlength{\headsep}{26pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}

\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{curves}

\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot, pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\usetikzlibrary[positioning,patterns]
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\usepackage{young}
\usepackage[vcentermath]{youngtab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
   witharrow/.style={postaction={decorate}},
   shorten <>/.style={shorten <=#1,shorten >=#1},
   dot/.style={radius=2pt}
  ]


  % ellipse
  \begin{scope}
    \fill 
          (-2,0) coordinate (h1) circle[dot] node[left](k1){$q$}
          (2,0) coordinate (h2) circle[dot] node[below](k2){$v_0$}
          (4,2) coordinate (h3) circle[dot] node[above](k3){$v_2$}
          (5,-2) coordinate (h4) circle[dot] node[below](p3){$v_1$}
          (0,0) coordinate (a3)  node[left](p3){}

          (5,0.5) coordinate (b3)  node[right]{}
          (1,-0.5) coordinate (c3) node[right]{};


     \draw[bend right=20,witharrow]  (h1) to node [anchor=south]{$\alpha(v_0)$} (h2);      
      \draw[bend left=30,witharrow]  (h1) to node [anchor=south]{$\alpha(v_2)$} (h3);       
       \draw[bend right=30,witharrow]  (h1) to node [anchor=north]{$\alpha(v_1)$} (h4);    
          \draw[bend right=30,witharrow]  (h2) to node [anchor=south]{$\sigma^{(1)}$} (h3); 
           \draw[bend left=20,witharrow]  (h2) to node [anchor=north]{$\sigma^{(2)}$} (h4); 
          \draw[bend left=25,witharrow]  (h3) to node [anchor=west]{$\sigma^{(0)}$} (h4); 
\draw ($0.5*(a3)+0.5*(b3)$) circle[x radius=6,y radius=4];
    \node at ($(a3)+(6,2.5)$) (X3) {$X$};      
    \draw[fill=red!30, opacity=.5] (h2)--(h3)--(h4)--cycle;    
\end{scope}          
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this problem? Can any one give me some idea?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi there, this code works on my computer.

Comment: I don't see `\documentclass` nor `usepackage`s nor `begin{document}` etc… It may work on you because you have a specific class and a specific package loaded… but if you don't complete your post with the needed information, it's gonna be hard to help you

Comment: I am sorry.  I have just added what you say

Comment: Please help us help you and make your example a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Sorry, but your example is not that minimal…

Comment: I've just tried to reduce the code a little bit.

Comment: perhaps this is helpful: [Tikz: shading region bounded by several curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140312/579)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
        \path [fill=red!30, opacity=.5] (h2) to [ bend right=30] (h3) to [ bend left=25] (h4) to [ bend right=20] (h2);
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{epsfig,psfrag}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym,amscd,amsthm}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.2in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.3in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.7in}
\setlength{\voffset}{-.7in}
\setlength{\headsep}{26pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}

\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{curves}

\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot, pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
\usetikzlibrary[positioning,patterns]
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\usepackage{young}
\usepackage[vcentermath]{youngtab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
   witharrow/.style={postaction={decorate}},
   shorten <>/.style={shorten <=#1,shorten >=#1},
   dot/.style={radius=2pt}
  ]

  \begin{scope}
    \fill 
          (2,0) coordinate (h2) circle[dot] node[below](k2){$v_0$}
          (4,2) coordinate (h3) circle[dot] node[above](k3){$v_2$}
          (5,-2) coordinate (h4) circle[dot] node[below](p3){$v_1$};

          \draw[bend right=30,witharrow]  (h2) to node [anchor=south]{$\sigma^{(1)}$} (h3); 
           \draw[bend left=20,witharrow]  (h2) to node [anchor=north]{$\sigma^{(2)}$} (h4); 
          \draw[bend left=25,witharrow]  (h3) to node [anchor=west]{$\sigma^{(0)}$} (h4); 


 \path [fill=red!30, opacity=.5] (h2) to [ bend right=30] (h3) to [ bend left=25] (h4) to [ bend right=20] (h2); 
\end{scope}          
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Not only does your code solve my problem but also a good example for me about MWE. I am new to latex :D

Comment: Right.(I think some packages more can reduced...). Have fun with LaTeX. Here you can find strategies to reduce your code to get a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that . The MWE makes it easier for everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

Bobyandbob already showed you how to fill that region, so this is more of a comment in a way, with some additional notes on your code.

- To change page margins etc., you should in general use the `geometry` package instead of setting the lengths manually like you do. That is, use something like

  ```
  \usepackage[
    textwidth=6.2in,
    textheight=8.7in,
    headsep=26pt
    ]{geometry}
  ```
- The `epsfig` package is superseded by `graphicx`, there's no need to use it. (Nowadays it is really just a wrapper around `graphicx` anyway.) If you need to include `.eps` files, use `\includegraphics{filename}`, as usual.
- You're loading several TikZ libraries twice, which is not necessary. And at one place you have `\usetikzlibrary[..]` instead of `\usetikzlibrary{..}` (it still works apparently, but the latter is the documented approach).
- As far as minimal examples, the code below is more minimal, as bobyandbob mentions, your preamble has a lot of stuff that is not relevant.
- I would suggest drawing the dots after the lines and the filling.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},
   witharrow/.style={postaction={decorate}},
   shorten <>/.style={shorten <=#1,shorten >=#1},
   dot/.style={radius=2pt}
  ]

\fill 
          (-2,0)   coordinate (h1) node[left](k1){$q$}
          (2,0)    coordinate (h2) node[below](k2){$v_0$}
          (4,2)    coordinate (h3) node[above](k3){$v_2$}
          (5,-2)   coordinate (h4) node[below](p3){$v_1$}
          (0,0)    coordinate (a3)
          (5,0.5)  coordinate (b3)
          (1,-0.5) coordinate (c3);


\fill[red!30,opacity=.5]
 (h2) to[bend right=30] (h3)
      to[bend left=25]  (h4) 
      to[bend right=20] (h2);

\draw[bend right=20,witharrow]  (h1) to node [anchor=south]{$\alpha(v_0)$} (h2);      
\draw[bend left=30,witharrow]   (h1) to node [anchor=south]{$\alpha(v_2)$} (h3);       
\draw[bend right=30,witharrow]  (h1) to node [anchor=north]{$\alpha(v_1)$} (h4);    
\draw[bend right=30,witharrow]  (h2) to node [anchor=south]{$\sigma^{(1)}$} (h3); 
\draw[bend left=20,witharrow]   (h2) to node [anchor=north]{$\sigma^{(2)}$} (h4); 
\draw[bend left=25,witharrow]   (h3) to node [anchor=west]{$\sigma^{(0)}$} (h4); 
\draw ($0.5*(a3)+0.5*(b3)$) circle[x radius=6,y radius=4];
\node at ($(a3)+(6,2.5)$) (X3) {$X$};      

\foreach \x in {h1,h2,h3,h4}
   \fill (\x) circle[dot];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```