# Noisy, analogue waveform in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, audio

Is there an easy way of drawing a noisy waveform in TikZ? I know you can draw a simple sinusoid by repeatedly using cos and sin for every half-period, but doing that for a noisy waveform seems like a massive undertaking and a very roundabout way of doing it.

I'm looking for something like this: [image: Noisy waveform]

It doesn't have to be that long, a fifth of the length is fine. I'm diagramming a noise reduction system and need to show a noisy waveform as the input to the diagram (whereas the rest of the diagram is simple rectangular boxes and text...).

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [Plotting a random function f(x) and f(x)+sin(x) with tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126838)

Comment: Thanks for that. I just discovered TikZ today and it's surprisingly powerful!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `\draw plot` for plotting functions. For the noise, you can use the `rand` function.

In general, plotting is more comfortable using the PGFPlots package, which builds on PGF/TikZ:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[samples=200, domain=0:5*360]
        \begin{axis}[
            width=10cm, height=4cm,
            enlarge x limits=false,
            xtick=\empty,
            axis lines*=middle,
            hide y axis
        ]
        \addplot [no markers, smooth] {sin(x)+rand*2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why sin(x) and not only rand?

Comment: I just think it's a prettier function than pure noise. No technical reason though (but jodles did ask for a "noisy waveform" and not "pure noise", so I guess it's closer to what they were looking for)

Comment: OK.  I need white noise and I am using something like +rand-rand+rand-rand to make it as random as possible.

Comment: @Pygmalion: I don't think that actually increases the randomness. It does change the distribution of your values, though, which might be undesirable: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3956538/1456857

Comment: @Jake Thanks for the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956478 hint!

Answer (score 12):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\psset{plotpoints=200,linejoin=1}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}

\begin{document}
\psLoop{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-4,-2)(4.5,2.5)
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none,linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-4,-2)(4,2)[$t$,0][$v$,90]
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-3.8}{3.8}{x 5 mul RadtoDeg sin Rand 4 mul 1 sub mul 1.8 mul}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Attention

Note that `Rand` no longer produces a random real number between 0 and 0.5 inclusive. Its definition had been tacitly changed. Now it produces a random real number between 0 and 1 inclusive. It is not documented, nor announced, but it is still fun!

The code given above has not been updated yet so it will produce different output. I have no time to update it right now. Sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: A plot continuously moving from right to left would be even cooler.

Comment: @AlexG: Yes. I will see it later.

Comment: This is not working :(

Answer (score 12):

This is a derived example from the »[PGF/TikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)« user guide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
      excitation(\t,\w) = sin(\t*\w);
      noise = rnd - 0.5;
      source(\t) = excitation(\t,20) + noise;
      filter(\t) = 1 - abs(sin(mod(\t, 50)));
      speech(\t) = 1 + source(\t)*filter(\t);
    }
  ]
    \draw[help lines] (0,1) -- (3,1);
    \draw[blue, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=1cm] (0,1) -- plot [domain=0:360, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{speech(\x)});
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Customization is left to you.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the noise part without any sinusoidal excitation, you can customize the Donig's code by just removing the sinusoidal excitation. In addition, you can shift the noise location by just adding the xshift and yshift commands, as

```
\documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}   
 \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
                declare function={
                 noise = rnd - 0.1;
                speech(\t) = noise; 
             }
          ]
   \draw[help lines] (0,1) -- (1,1);
      \draw[blue, thick, x=0.0415cm, y=1.15cm, yshift=-6cm] (0,1) -- plot [domain=0:360, samples=1044, smooth] (\x,{speech(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ONLY RANDOM NOISE with 1044 SAMPLES]

Comment: is it possible to let the noise originate from a \node? when i say originate from (nodea.east) it does not work

Comment: When using a node coordinate like (node.east) as the seed for the random number generator, you need to make sure that the coordinates are converted to a number using \pgfmathparse and \pgfmathresult, since the \pgfmathsetseed command expects a number as its argument. 

To generate the noise function from a node, you can use the \pgfmathsetseed command to set the random number generator seed based on the coordinates of the node.